# React Native Navigation Title

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Apparently simple problem: the Header Title in react Navigation

Navigator file with my Bottom Tabs

```js
const BottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    ToFind: {
      screen: TopBarNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Discover",
        tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
          return (
            <Ionicons
              name="md-search"
              size={25}
              color={tabInfo.tintColor} //prende lo stesso colore di tintcolor giù
            />
          );
        },
        tabBarColor: "#27ae60",
        activeColor: "white",
      },
    },
```

....

```js
const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  BottomTabNavigator,
  Detail: DetailScreen, // not visible but I need the navigation
  Item: ItemDisplay,  // not visible but I need the navigation
});
```

Now I try to set the name into the page (at the bottom)

```js
MapScreen.navigationOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: "Map",
  };
};
```

Doing this I have the Bottom Tabs styled as I want and navigation but **I CAN'T change the header title** (navigation title) but I always see **BottomTabNavigator**
It looks really trick or I'm mistaking somewhere?
Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: where did you place the `MapScreen` in your navigator? keep in mind that you can set `headerTitle` just on the screens which are placed in the `StackNavigator`, not in the `BottomTabNavigator`.

Comment: yes I know it, `Map Screen` is in the `BottomTabNavigator` but even if I put it in the `stackNavigator` it doesn't allow me to setup the title

Answer (score 0):

createMaterialBottomTabNavigator does not have header bar by default, but createStackNavigator has.

You can do something like this.

```
import React from "React";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const Tab1 = createStackNavigator({
    S1: {
        screen: ToFind
    }
});

const Tab2 = createStackNavigator({
    S2: {
        screen: ToFind
    }
});

export default createAppContainer(
    createBottomTabNavigator({
        Tab1,
        Tab2
    }, {
        //CUSTOM CONFIG
        initialRouteName: 'Tab1',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === 'Tab1') {
                    iconName = 'icon1';
                } else if (routeName === 'Tab2') {
                    iconName = 'icon2';
                }
                return <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={tintColor} />;
                <Ionicons
                    name={iconName}
                    size={25}
                    color={tabInfo.tintColor} //prende lo stesso colore di tintcolor giù
                />
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            showLabel: false,
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#27ae60',
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                borderTopColor: '#27ae60',
            },
        },
    });
);
```

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work, cause like that I can't setup all the styling  unless you know how to do it

Comment: The header title part working fine? we can work on setup styling.

Comment: yes it works but I have lost all the styling and I have just a purple bottom bar with no icons

Comment: I have updated my answer with styling, please check if it is working or not.

Comment: thanks but is not gonna work cause my styling has different `tabBarColor` for every icon (screen)

Comment: you can set the color in state based on your tab selection and update the tabbarcolor.

Comment: thanks but it's too complicated. I'd to create 4 different conditions if else to set the styling.  Even if it works I don't see this as a solution

Comment: I have found the solution tomorrow I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. Hope to fix your problem.

1. Create Your Bottom Tab Navigator :

```
const BottomTabNavigator =  createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    PageOne: {
      screen: PageOneComponent,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Feather name="airplay" size={26} color={tintColor} />,
        tabBarLabel: null,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', elevation: 0, }
      },
    },
    PageTwo: {
      screen: PageTwoComponent,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Feather name="search" size={25} color={tintColor}/>,
        tabBarLabel: null,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', elevation: 0, }
      }
    },
    MapViewLink: {
      screen: MapView,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: <Feather name="map-pin" size={25} color={'green'} />,
        tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
          navigation.navigate('MapView');
        },
        tabBarLabel: null
      }
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'PageOne',
    activeColor: 'orange',
    inactiveColor: 'grey',
    labeled: false,
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', elevation: 0, borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor: '#efefef' },
  }
);
```

2. Create your StackNavigator and export the navigator

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  // bottom tab navigator
  BottomTabNavigator: {
    screen: BottomTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },

  // MapView Page 
  MapView: {
     screen: MapView,
     navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Hello World'
     })
  },
}, {
defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      // the default styles you want to apply to header title
    },
});

export default  createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

3. In the end, put the navigator inside the main project file. e.g `App.js`